# Need to format my json output a little better

Tags: json, console

I'm trying to make a nice representation of the console.log onto the page itself.
I have the following:

```
window.PRINT = function() {
   if(this.console) { 
      console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
   }

   var X = $('#PRINT');
   if (!X) {
      $('body').append('<p id="PRINT"></p>');
      X = $('#PRINT');
   }
   $.each(arguments, function(Index,  Value) {
      X.append('<p>' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '</p>');
   });
};
```

The problem is when I use it for

```
$('input').change(function(myEvent) { 
   PRINT(myEvent,this); 
});
```

It doesn't really do a very good job of printing out the objects and their contents.
I wonder if there's a json formatter somewhere.
I'm not talking about a Firefox plugin, I mean: one that accepts json coming in and outputs a nice html representation of it, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

- [JSON2HTML Bloopletech](https://github.com/bloopletech/json2html)

  - [Demo page](http://json.bloople.net/)
- [Zach Hunter's JSON to HTML](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table/)

  - [Demo project](http://www.zachhunter.com/wp-content/uploads/JsonToHTML.zip) (download)

Answer (score 1):

if you're just looking to visualize JSON use something like

[visualizer.json2html.com](http://visualizer.json2html.com)

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you for telling me about that!